# Spark AR - Enable animation from script to patch editor

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

Im trying to start/enable an animation from script to patch editor but somehow cant accomplish that.
 Any help/idea people?
Thanks

In the editor I created a "pulse" in "From Script" called "myPulse"  and patch that to patch editor. From script I created `const myPulse = true;` and to check if its work `Diagnostics.log(myPulse);`. On console I get "true" but in patch editor nothing true, it stays "false" or at least it doesnt enable the animation.

```
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Patches = require('Patches');
const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');

const myPulse = true;

Diagnostics.log(myPulse);
```

I expect "myPulse" will turn "true" to patch editor to start the animation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using state machine:

```
const Patches = require('Patches');

const Walking = 0;
const Eating = 1;
let state = Walking;

function StartEating() {
    state = Eating;
    Patches.setScalarValue('state', state);
}

function StartWalking() {
    state = Walking;
    Patches.setScalarValue('state', state);
}

// some logic for switching states (e.g. reacting on tap)
```

Then add **from script** value:

[image: Asing **state** value]

And in patch editor link proper animation states:

[image: Linking animation states in patch editor]

Important note:

You may experience some issues with freezing or not switching animations - depend on platform, Spark AR version, etc. However on mobile device it should be fine.